# tickInterval & categories. Only first category shows

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to show the ticks on my chart at specific intervals. So I have used 'tickInterval: 46' in the chart options. However, the default values of the x=axis show 0, 46, 92 etc, I would like to just show values 1, 2, 3, .. etc. If I use ...

```
    xAxis: {

        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
        tickInterval: 46
    }
```

My very first tick on the chart gets labelled '1', but the other tick values follow the original ordering. So my new x-axis values follow '1, 46', 92, 138 etc.

May I ask for your help to display my required values on the x=axis please. I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

The fiddle below shows the issue I am having.

Many thanks.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyRS/91Lahn7h/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick ...

```
    xAxis: {                

                tickInterval: 23,
                tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                labels: {
                            style: {
                                        fontSize: '8px',
                                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                    },
                            formatter: function() {
                                if (this.isFirst){
                                    return 0;
                                } else {
                                    return (this.value / 23);
                                }
                            }
                        },
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

The categories are numbered from 0 to length of array. Setting 46 as tickInterval, means that you select first index and 46 index of categories array. So better is remove categories, and use numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't always the case ... just discovered the 'formatter:' function and think I have sorted things. Will update the post pointing out what I've done.